# Kubectl logs command unable to print the output

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have a docker image of my kafka_consumer code which is consuming messages from a topic. Now what i did was that i created a pod out of my docker image which is running successfully. When i issue the command
kubectl logs  it just prints first three lines of logs and then exits. When i run the docker image it gives me complete output where in consumer record is printed several times. What is wrong with kubernetes logs then?

I tried using `kubectl logs <pod-name>` which returns me only 3 lines of logs.

I expect the output to show the proper detailed messages which will look like this:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

ConsumerRecord(topic = tt, partition = 0, offset = 399219, CreateTime = 1565941033699, serialized key size = 3, serialized value size = 6, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = key, value = hello )
```

When i use kubectl i get only first three lines of log4j and not the ConsumerRecord.

Comment: Can you provide the pod's YAML code and the command you had used to start docker container like "docker run" command.

Comment: maybe the output is not there yet? if you want to show a live log, you can add the `-f`option (for "follow"), and the log stays open and prints any new outputs.

Comment: @SubramanianManickam i did not use any yaml file for creating the pod. I used the command kubectl run --images. Also the command for docker was: docker run --net=host -it demo:try

Comment: @MarkusDresch I tried doing that as well but no luck. It doesnt exit but it is just stuck there with no further outputs.

Comment: in that case, there is no more output. you can enter the pod using `kubectl exec <podname> -- /bin/bash` or similar to do more debugging.

Comment: @MarkusDresch The same docker image when run through docker run command gives infinite output of consumer records. That is what i am seeking for.

Comment: well, then it can't get any records. i don't know where your consumer records come from, if they are from some database or file system you probably have some connectivity issue. (ok looks like they come from kafka, but still, it's most probably some connectivity issue, add more logs to your application)

Comment: @MarkusDresch Is it something related to my host network because if i run my docker command without --net=host it gives only three lines of output. If so, how can i specify that using kubectl.

Answer (score 1):

When you `kubectl logs` to any pod, you're [querying the `stdout/stderr` streams sent to the node's log files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level) (`/var/log/*`), which in turn depends on the underlying host OS logrotate.

You can try to determine if this is the problem by either, comparing the logs from `kubectl logs` versus the ones sent into a [logging backend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures) (if any, for instance *Fluentd* or the *ELK stack*) or directly *SSHing* into the node and locating them directly in the logging path.

There aren't many details on how are you running your Kubernetes cluster, but the information provided strongly suggests that this is a node level issue, specific to how pod logs are being managed internally.

Finally, the approach using `kubectl exec <podname> -- /bin/bash` is a good idea to determine if the container is locally storing these logs and the issue is when they're sent into the host node.

Comment: Please clarify your question as I don't see the relationship with the logging system.

Comment: I got the above working by passing a kafka cluster ip for bootstrap servers. I realized that this problem arose only when i tried to pass ip of kafka server installed locally on my machine. Could not get it to working with local kafka server though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kubectl logs --follow [Pod name] -c [Container name]`, this will show you the realtime logs

adding the `--follow` will let you view logs in real time

Comment: I have mentioned the same in the discussion area that i tried this but the same problem persists i. e getting only first three lines of output and nothing else after that.

Comment: can you try using `--tail=20` just to see if you get more than 3 lines of logs

Comment: it has only three lines of logs anyways even if i run with docker run. I feel the problem is that my kafka is running locally and i am using --net=host with my docker run command. Do you have any idea how to replicate this behaviour with kuberentes pods?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was that the pod was not able to connect to local kafka which was installed in my system. That is why it was not able to print any record from kafka. What i did was i used an external kafka cluster and then it started working as expected.